# Show subcategory name selected in specific category woocoommerce

Tags: php, javascript, html, categories

Hi basically I have categori ID number (134) that has 2 child of that (red and blue). I selected the blue one. I want to display only the selected one (blue). But at the moment the show all subcategories  (red and blue). Please help me here my code

```
$args = array(
   'hierarchical' => 1,
   'show_option_none' => '',
   'hide_empty' => 0,
   'parent' => 134,
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
  foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
    $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
      echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

Here for single product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display only assigned category you need to change **hide_empty** to true.

Please see the modified code:

```
$args = array(
 'hierarchical' => 1,
 'show_option_none' => '',
 'hide_empty' => true,
 'parent' => 134,
 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
$link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
  echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Please see the updated code:

```
$cats_list = get_the_terms ( get_the_ID() , 'product_cat' );

echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
foreach ($cats_list as $cats) {
$link = get_term_link( $cats->slug, $cats->taxonomy );
echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$cats->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: OMG you are right!! thank you so muchhh

Comment: Hi sorry another problem, just realized it show all the subcategories which didn't selected in that product. can you please check this link?
http://baliartsgallery.com/product/wonderful-dreamland-l1-painting/

Comment: @WildaSagita, Please try this code to get product's assigned categories: 
    $terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     $cat_id = $term->id;
   }

Comment: Hi sorry I'm very beginner, can you please explain  me more for the full code?

Comment: You want to display categories assigned to the product. Right?

Comment: Yes I want display subcategories name in single product page

Comment: Please see the updated code given above.

Comment: I tried but nothing show. sorry

Comment: Please show me the code how you have added.

Comment: Ok, but at the moment the category still show. (I want only show subcategories not categories) and also I want only show the subcategory from category ID 134.
Please help me